# How do I get an event to fire as soon as an object's constructor has finished?

Tags: vb.net, events, constructor

Research tells me that raising an event from the constructor itself is not feasible as the object may not be fully initialised... so where can I fire an event from as soon as the constructor has fired?

Comment: is this a Control, Component or a basic class?

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry - just a class straight up

Comment: are you after something like a `Initialized` event?  who is the listener?

Comment: that's what I've been searching for.... I'm creating characters for a battle game that reports actions in a log that get generated off events within the class, for instance successfully attacking an opponent or dying, but I want to generate a log entry for when a character respawns. It obviously doesn't have to fire in the constructor, but I want it to be internal and happen as soon as the object is done instantiating.

Comment: in that case, why not just add a log entry directly or thru a method?  The event listener is the problem.  e.g `Log.AddLine("Giant Death Robot created...)"`

Comment: yeah I was just creating a new object then calling a function within the object to generate the log entry... everything else was working so smoothly with events, i was just hoping to keep things uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is add a method to handle additional post ctor tasks:

```
Friend Class FooBar

     Public Sub New
         ' your code here
     End Sub

     Public Sub Create
        ' do anything you want
     End Sub

End Class
```

Elsewhere:

```
Friend WithEvents Foo As Foobar

' ...
Foo = New FooBar      '  Foo doesnt exist until ctor code executes and the
                      ' code returns to here. 

Foo.Create            ' do whatever you like, as long as any other
                      ' objects referenced have been created.
```

The reason calling a sub from the ctor to raise an event wont work with a class is this:

```
Private Sub SomeEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Foo.SomeEvent
    Console.Beep()
End Sub
```

the key is `Handles Foo.SomeEvent`

There is no `Foo` yet to handle the event.  It doesnt crash and there event is raised, but there is no object for the listener to catch/handle the event.  Enough of a form is created in `InitializeComponents`, that it does work with a form.

There might also be an Interface to implement something like this, I know of some for Components, but not classes.

Comment: Yeah that's basically what my research has come up with to this point. When I tried to raise the event in New() simply nothing happened. Nice workaround though, not quite what I wanted but at least keeps it encapsulated, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Load or Show events from the Shown.

```
   Private Sub myForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown

   End Sub
```

or

```
 Private Sub myForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding an [Action(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter to your constructor and invoke the delegate on the very last line.

```
Public Class Foo

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As Action(Of Foo))
        '...
        '...
        '...
        If (Not action Is Nothing) Then action.Invoke(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Example**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, ev As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim foo1 As New Foo("foo1", AddressOf Me.HandleFooCtor)
        Dim foo2 As New Foo("foo2", Sub(f As Foo) MessageBox.Show(f.Name))
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleFooCtor(f As Foo)
        MessageBox.Show(f.Name)
    End Sub

    Public Class Foo

        Public Sub New(name As String, Optional ByVal action As Action(Of Foo) = Nothing)
            '...
            '...
            '...
            Me.Name = name
            If (Not action Is Nothing) Then action.Invoke(Me)
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Name As String

    End Class

End Class
```