# vb.net After Contruction trigger

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to trigger "sub After_Contruction" after Contruction **automatically**? I **want** to use shortcut-properties and I am creating an instance of "child", e.g.:

```
    class Parent
       public sub new(i as integer)
          MsgBox (Me.x.ToString,, "in Parent.new (here x is 0)")
       end sub
       protected overridable ReadOnly property x as integer = 0
       public sub After_Contruction
          MsgBox (Me.x.ToString,, "in Parent.After_Contruction via Child (here x is 9)")
       end sub
    end class

    class Child : inherits Parent
       public sub new()
            MyBase.new(1)
            MsgBox (Me.x.ToString,, "in Child.new (here x is 9)")
       end sub
       protected overrides ReadOnly property x as integer = 9
    end class
```

Comment: just call `After_Contruction` in child constructor. or i'm missing something !?

Comment: If you create an instance of Child then x will never be 0, even in the Parent constructor.

Comment: I can of course call After_Contruction in child constructor, but I don't want to that,it should be automatic. Otherwise I have to do this in **every** Child (dont repeat yourself = DRY pattern)

Comment: jmcilhinney: it is 0 in the Parent Constructor, please let it run.

Comment: OK, that's a new one on me. That said, I guess that that just shows that I have never abused a constructor like this. The point of a constructor is to build an object so getting its properties when you should be, if anything, setting them.

Comment: As for the question, there's no such thing as triggering a method automatically. The only way to execute a method is to call it. Even event handlers get called, although it's buried inside a delegate and the `RaiseEvent` statement. If you want to execute that method at the end of the constructor of a derived class then call the method. DRY doesn't mean don't call the same method twice. As I alluded to in my previous comment though, I wonder whether you're doing the wrong thing altogether. I'd be interested to know what the real code looks like.

Comment: jmcilhinney: the real code is a definition base class with a Child class for every customer where each Customer (can) have an short-form override like this:  (new line)  
protected overrides ReadOnly property x as integer = 9  (new line)  the base class should precompute values based on overridden values

Comment: OK, DRY is perhaps not the correct pattern, I mean that the base class is responsible to pre-compute something on the **overridden** properties, the Child's should not be responsible

Comment: "with a Child class for every customer " I hope you mean an instance of the Child class, not a separate class for each customer.

Comment: What is the purpose of x? Is it meant to distinguish an instance of Parent from an instance of child?

Comment: Could you do something like create a Must Override method in your Parent, call that from the parent constructor, then override it and do your magic in the inherited class?

Comment: Mary, every Customer has separate Child class with his Settings, all properties are Setting properties (about 100), Customer a has x = 9, Customer b has x = 19 for example. The Base class should "take" these Values and make Precomputations for the Base class functionality. My goal is to trigger Precomputations, but not in **every** Child class (can be forgotten)

Comment: This might be an artifact of how VB implements auto properties in that syntax, where the value assigned to the underlying property variable may happen in the ctor.  What happens if your property is instead done as a block of code that returns 9?  I think you would always get 9 in the parent in that case.  You might also check the current behavior by putting a breakpoint on the assignment of 9 to the property and see where it fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB implementation of auto properties of this form:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property x As Integer = 9
```

Defers assignment to the underlying variable until after the base class constructor has been called.  You can verify this by setting some breakpoints strategically.  This behavior is not obvious from the syntax of the child constructor, which misleadingly implies that the child class is initialized before `MyBase.New` is called.

If you use the following form instead, it will always return 9:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property x As Integer
    Get
        Return 9
    End Get
End Property
```

If this isn't suitable due to details that you omitted as part of simplifying the question, you can use an `Overridable` or `MustOverride` routine to ensure that this setup has already occurred during the base class constructor (as Hursey suggested).

As an aside: It's interesting to contemplate whether it would make sense to change this behavior at the language level.  My best guess is that the current behavior is to avoid problems with trying to have a property depend on anything from the base class when the base class might not be fully initialized yet.  It would be safe to have an exception for compile-time constants (`constexpr` in C++ lingo), but that could introduce confusing inconsistency with non-constant values; I think the current behavior is the most correct in the general sense assuming that the child-class property initialization might depend on things requiring base-class initialization.

Comment: Craig, that is true, you always get 9. But there are 100 properties, so I want to use the short form. I think for me there is no other solution than using the long form. Or delay the Usage in Base class until it is needed.

Comment: @Marcus I'm afraid that's the case.  The virtual init function might be easier to implement in that case, since you might be able to convert it with copy/paste and find/replace in the editor vs. having to transform them all to long form by hand.  I'm not sure (haven't tested) whether you can assign to the underlying implicit variable for a read-only property through a non-ctor function on the object; `ReadOnly` variables are typically only assignable in the ctor.

Comment: just found this, but didn't solve my "problem" because only the Base class should "do" things:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552030/how-do-i-get-an-event-to-fire-as-soon-as-an-objects-constructor-has-finished

Comment: also found in Wikipedia:  
In Objective-C, the constructor method is split across two methods, "alloc" and "init" with the alloc method setting aside (allocating) memory for an instance of the class, and the init method handling the bulk of initializing the instance. A call to the method "new" invokes both the alloc and the init methods, for the class instance.